Как организовать базу данных для корзины и заказов с учетом цен и скидок?
Таблицы имеющейся на данный момент:
Product



id
title



Size



id
title



Sku



id
product_id
size_id
quantity



Схемы условные*
Есть предположения что сама корзина по сути это как неоформленный заказ, и после заказа, ее состояние сменяется, хотя есть и второй вариант развития событий, это когда после оформления все товар перебрасываются из одной таблицы (cart_product), в другую (order_product)

"сама корзина по сути это как неоформленный заказ" - это может быть рабочим варинтом. Тогда cart_product не нужна, просто в order_product пометить как "неоформленный", например.

Если относится к поставленной задаче, как к коммерческому проекту, то можно сделать так:

Таблицы:

Users: Какие-нибудь формальные колонки по типу user_id, username, password и т.п.;
Products: product_id, name, discount, stock_quantity(кол-во товара на складе);
Cart: cart_id(тут можно использовать user_id), created(когда корзина создана), updated(когда корзина была обновлена);
cart_products(товары в корзине): cart_product_id, cart_id(user_id), product_id, quantity;
orders: order_id, user_id, order_status, total_price(общая цена со скидкой);
order_products: order_product_id(лучше у каждого из них будет свой id), order_id, product_id, quantity, price.


Что насчет подходов, что ты привел:

В принципе можно использовать корзину как неоформленный заказ, тогда можно использовать таблицу cart для хранения информации о корзине и таблицу cart_products для хранения товаров в корзине. А уже при оформлении заказа просто меняешь статус корзины и перемещаешь товары в таблицу order_products
С другой же стороны, если переносить товары из одной таблицы в другую, то в случае оформления заказа товары(в нашем случае таблицы) из cart_products можно скопировать в order_products, а после просто очищать корзину/удалять.
В общем, если нужно сохранять историю заказов - выбирай второй вариант, если нужно управлять состоянием корзины и заказа в одном месте - первый


если ответ вам помог - отметьте его галочкой
